# Search through a dictionary with nested dictionaries and lists, for a string, and return adjacent string

Tags: python

I have a dictionary that has been configured with nested dictionaries and lists. My objective is to make a function that iterates through it and searches for the 'name' of a given track and then returns the 'uri' value. The difficulty is that 'uri' is not a key to 'name'. But 'name' and 'uri' are in matching order. For example, searching the name 'Marionette' should return the uri value 'spotify:track:7K79eftHsp3THzMzKAvdwf'. Please see example code below:

````
 'spotify:album:1fZZFPgIGWwGLGdaBtfTB2': {'album': ['Bloom',
   'Bloom',
   'Bloom',
   'Bloom',
   'Bloom',
   'Bloom',
   'Bloom',
   'Bloom',
   'Bloom',
   'Bloom',
   'Bloom'],
  'track_number': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11],
  'id': ['7K79eftHsp3THzMzKAvdwf',
   '50p5GVTOaUwS24rDGj6Nvv',
   '1wX0mdaFOVF7QSxh3oMZFu',
   '6EgjqSpLfGLYAY8xJKS3oI',
   '21FWZSYUk3HucbogowQkL3',
   '4I2Xc5VoEHKILATMeRPcAR',
   '22Fwp9jLBVF25Zt0NKwjgO',
   '0MoASguy3Rqj6go8yjyXDG',
   '3yY8DTJHs0rjXi0sgc7oVD',
   '2ntYoR04fzRYAOoowJzuod',
   '4AYe20dLcciEY7uhjnxpjp'],
  'name': ['Marionette',
   'WILDSIDE',
   'SAPPY',
   'Jackpot',
   '#Cookie Jar',
   'Snap Snap',
   'Sayonara',
   'Aitai-tai',
   'Swimming Pool',
   "'Cause it's you",
   'Color of Love'],
  'uri': ['spotify:track:7K79eftHsp3THzMzKAvdwf',
   'spotify:track:50p5GVTOaUwS24rDGj6Nvv',
   'spotify:track:1wX0mdaFOVF7QSxh3oMZFu',
   'spotify:track:6EgjqSpLfGLYAY8xJKS3oI',
   'spotify:track:21FWZSYUk3HucbogowQkL3',
   'spotify:track:4I2Xc5VoEHKILATMeRPcAR',
   'spotify:track:22Fwp9jLBVF25Zt0NKwjgO',
   'spotify:track:0MoASguy3Rqj6go8yjyXDG',
   'spotify:track:3yY8DTJHs0rjXi0sgc7oVD',
   'spotify:track:2ntYoR04fzRYAOoowJzuod',
   'spotify:track:4AYe20dLcciEY7uhjnxpjp']},
 'spotify:album:3rVtm00UfbuzWOewdm4iYM': {'album': ['‘The ReVe Festival’ Finale',
   '‘The ReVe Festival’ Finale',
   '‘The ReVe Festival’ Finale',
   '‘The ReVe Festival’ Finale',
   '‘The ReVe Festival’ Finale',
   '‘The ReVe Festival’ Finale',
   '‘The ReVe Festival’ Finale',
   '‘The ReVe Festival’ Finale',
   '‘The ReVe Festival’ Finale',
   '‘The ReVe Festival’ Finale',
   '‘The ReVe Festival’ Finale',
   '‘The ReVe Festival’ Finale',
   '‘The ReVe Festival’ Finale',
   '‘The ReVe Festival’ Finale',
   '‘The ReVe Festival’ Finale',
   '‘The ReVe Festival’ Finale'],
  'track_number': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16],
  'id': ['3CYH422oy1cZNoo0GTG1TK',
   '2iYnEfKsAsE86Yb9mS4b3E',
   '2m9K7KlDOQ0NXk9xBpkuoZ',
   '5vdqSjUj9JZsAHdr02Vygk',
   '1wpAS4Jm9ElkOJjnyDX4Tm',
   '3q21kVfUIdkzqYpzBCbojN',
   '12okmCNziVZkDIcEOx0SD9',
   '2KqYLFNTX2HXzYH4bucBKa',
   '0HFa5Rr2x5iwqIvGTMqif6',
   '7gs7h249FMYC3U02BimoD6',
   '3lZHJ90cpbtLCyJNzL39Pb',
   '0tHkBl71ZHXaFdc0sNGQHz',
   '65ZHlbTuPrZggbmYCVjPL4',
   '782QoB4jJ7hEVJmkYzVrRE',
   '2cvi3IRTibXzmAm4f8P2HP',
   '1O7qPyMtudzP3APaOT2OTH'],
  'name': ['Psycho',
   'In & Out',
   'Remember Forever',
   'Eyes Locked, Hands Locked',
   'Ladies Night',
   "Jumpin'",
   'Love Is The Way',
   'Carpool',
   'Umpah Umpah',
   'LP',
   'Parade',
   'Bing Bing',
   'Milkshake',
   'Sunny Side Up!',
   'Zimzalabim',
   'La Rouge - Special Track'],
  'uri': ['spotify:track:3CYH422oy1cZNoo0GTG1TK',
   'spotify:track:2iYnEfKsAsE86Yb9mS4b3E',
   'spotify:track:2m9K7KlDOQ0NXk9xBpkuoZ',
   'spotify:track:5vdqSjUj9JZsAHdr02Vygk',
   'spotify:track:1wpAS4Jm9ElkOJjnyDX4Tm',
   'spotify:track:3q21kVfUIdkzqYpzBCbojN',
   'spotify:track:12okmCNziVZkDIcEOx0SD9',
   'spotify:track:2KqYLFNTX2HXzYH4bucBKa',
   'spotify:track:0HFa5Rr2x5iwqIvGTMqif6',
   'spotify:track:7gs7h249FMYC3U02BimoD6',
   'spotify:track:3lZHJ90cpbtLCyJNzL39Pb',
   'spotify:track:0tHkBl71ZHXaFdc0sNGQHz',
   'spotify:track:65ZHlbTuPrZggbmYCVjPL4',
   'spotify:track:782QoB4jJ7hEVJmkYzVrRE',
   'spotify:track:2cvi3IRTibXzmAm4f8P2HP',
   'spotify:track:1O7qPyMtudzP3APaOT2OTH']}}```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function and loop through the values in the dictionary, then iterate the `name` list for each of them, and if name is found, you just need to take value at corresponding index in `uri` list:

```py
def func_(d:dict, name:str)->str:
    for v in d.values():
        for idx, item in enumerate(v['name']):
            if item==name:
                return v['uri'][idx]
    raise ValueError("Name not found")

# Sample Run:
func_(d, 'Marionette')
Out[31]: 'spotify:track:7K79eftHsp3THzMzKAvdwf'
```